# Tono y vibración no para hasta que se cierra la aplicación

Tags: java, android

He estado desarrollando una aplicación en android, en la cual tengo que hacer reproducir un Ringtone (Alarma) y hacer que el teléfono vibre, sin embargo en algunas ocasiones cuando la aplicación esta en segundo plano o se utiliza el botón "Back", y se enciende la alarma no me permite apagar dicha Alarma, hasta que cierro la aplicación.

El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.pubnub.api.PNConfiguration;
import com.pubnub.api.PubNub;
import com.pubnub.api.callbacks.SubscribeCallback;
import com.pubnub.api.enums.PNStatusCategory;
import com.pubnub.api.models.consumer.PNStatus;
import com.pubnub.api.models.consumer.pubsub.PNMessageResult;
import com.pubnub.api.models.consumer.pubsub.PNPresenceEventResult;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Vibrator vibrator;
    private Ringtone defaultRingtone;
    private Button btnStop;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);

        //Toast.makeText(ScrollingActivity.this,"OnCreate",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        ScrollingActivity.this.defaultRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(ScrollingActivity.this, notification);
        ScrollingActivity.this.vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ScrollingActivity.this.btnStop = findViewById(R.id.btnStopAlarm);
        pubnubInstance();
        detenerAlarma(btnStop);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //Toast.makeText(ScrollingActivity.this,"OnStop",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    /*@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       //Toast.makeText(ScrollingActivity.this,"Button Back Lock",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }*/
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        ScrollingActivity.this.btnStop = findViewById(R.id.btnStopAlarm);
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ScrollingActivity.this.vibrator.hasVibrator()){
                    ScrollingActivity.this.vibrator.cancel();
                }
                if(ScrollingActivity.this.defaultRingtone.isPlaying()){
                    ScrollingActivity.this.defaultRingtone.stop();
                }
            }
        });

        //Toast.makeText(ScrollingActivity.this,"onResume",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_scrolling, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void detenerAlarma(Button btn){
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (vibrator.hasVibrator()) {
                    vibrator.cancel();
                }
                if(defaultRingtone.isPlaying()){
                    defaultRingtone.stop();
                }
            }
        });

    }
    public void iniciarAlarma(String tittle, String content){
        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "Notification.inf")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smartsoftwarelogob2_smal)
                .setContentTitle(tittle)
                .setContentText(content)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;
        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(ScrollingActivity.this);

        startVibrador();
        startRington(ScrollingActivity.this.defaultRingtone);
        notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }

    public void startVibrador(){
        if (ScrollingActivity.this.vibrator.hasVibrator()) {
            long[] pattern = {400, 500, 200, 300, 200, 150, 100, 75};
            ScrollingActivity.this.vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);
        }else{
            Log.v("NoVibrator","Vibrator no found");
        }
    }

    public void startRington(Ringtone rt){
        rt.play();
    }

    public void pubnubInstance(){
        final TextView connectStatus = findViewById(R.id.statusConnection);
        final TextView textViewName = findViewById(R.id.machineName);
        final TextView textViewTipo = findViewById(R.id.tvTipo);
        final TextView textViewUbicacion = findViewById(R.id.tvUbicacion);
        final TextView textViewMensaje = findViewById(R.id.tvMensaje);

        PNConfiguration pnConfiguration = new PNConfiguration();
        pnConfiguration.setSubscribeKey("sub-c-f49072d4-18bd-11e8-b857-da98488f5703");
        pnConfiguration.setPublishKey("pub-c-4348e254-4e80-4cc7-929f-357abb4b4908");
        pnConfiguration.setSecure(false);
        PubNub pubnub = new PubNub(pnConfiguration);

        pubnub.addListener(new SubscribeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void status(PubNub pubnub, PNStatus status) {
                if (status.getCategory() == PNStatusCategory.PNConnectedCategory) {
                    connectStatus.setText("Conectado");
                    connectStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#04B404"));
                }else{
                    connectStatus.setText("error" + status.getErrorData());
                    connectStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void message(PubNub pubnub, final PNMessageResult message) {
                final String machineName = message.getMessage().getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString();
                final String ubicacion = message.getMessage().getAsJsonObject().get("ubicacion").getAsString();
                final String mensaje = message.getMessage().getAsJsonObject().get("mensaje").getAsString();
                final String tipo = message.getMessage().getAsJsonObject().get("tipo").getAsString();


                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        }

                        textViewName.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                textViewName.setText(machineName);

                            }
                        });
                        textViewTipo.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                textViewTipo.setText(tipo);

                            }
                        });
                        textViewUbicacion.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                textViewUbicacion.setText(ubicacion);
                            }});
                        textViewMensaje.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                textViewMensaje.setText(mensaje);
                            }
                        });
                        iniciarAlarma("Evento: "+tipo,mensaje);
                    }
                }).start();
            }

            @Override
            public void presence(PubNub pubnub, PNPresenceEventResult presence) {

            }
        });
        pubnub.subscribe().channels(Arrays.asList("my_channel")).execute();
    }

}
```

Tengo un xml "content":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.smartsoftwaresystems.machinemonitor.ScrollingActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/InforCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/machineName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text=""/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="left">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="Tipo: "/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvTipo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="left">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="Ubicación: "/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvUbicacion"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="left">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="Mensaje: "/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvMensaje"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/btnCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingLeft="16sp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:text="@string/detener_alarma"/>
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnStopAlarm"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="@string/apagar"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/connectState" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/statusConnection"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

Si deseas detener la alarma cuando tu aplicación se encuentre en segundo plano (background), puedes usar el método `onPause()` y agregar el proceso para detener la alarma:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    detenerAlarma(btnStop);

}
```

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.